# touchpad not working suddenly in Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: touchpad, synaptics

I used touchpad well in my notebook till yesterday night.
But I booted my notebook a while ago, found touchpad doesn't work.

You know, There's nothing about touchpad in Ubuntu's system settings in my case, but just only about mouse stuff.

Look at this result of typing command `xinput list` please.

```
⎡ Virtual core pointer                      id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ Logitech USB Optical Mouse                id=11   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎣ Virtual core keyboard                     id=3    [master keyboard (2)]
    ↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard               id=5    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=6    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Video Bus                                 id=7    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ AT Translated Set 2 keyboard              id=8    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ MSI Laptop hotkeys                        id=9    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ MSI WMI hotkeys                           id=10   [slave  keyboard (3)]
```

As you see, nothing about touchpad or Synaptics.

I really wanna know about cause of this situation and how could I solve that problem?

I'm waiting for your answers. Thank you.

Comment: Not enough rep to comment yet but would like to add that this has just happened to me and a restart fixed it. In my case it was likely due to the system resuming after a forced hibernate from low battery.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it. Just nothing special. I rebooted my notebook and touchpad works well.
I think `psmodule` was not loaded at that time.

Here's another result of typing command `xinput list`

```
Virtual core pointer                        id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ Logitech USB Optical Mouse                id=8    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad                id=10   [slave  pointer  (2)]
```

As you see, you can find it,huh?

And here's other result of typing command `lsmod | grep psmouse`

```
psmouse               106593  0
```

And last one about touch pad log from `/var/log/Xorg.X.log`

```
[    31.874] (II) LoadModule: "synaptics"
[    31.874] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/input/synaptics_drv.so
[    31.874] (II) Module synaptics: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[    31.874]    compiled for 1.16.0, module version = 1.8.99
[    31.874]    Module class: X.Org XInput Driver
[    31.875]    ABI class: X.Org XInput driver, version 21.0
[    31.875] (II) Using input driver 'synaptics' for 'SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad'
```

Since I have used Ubuntu as OS in my notebook, I haven't had a case like this.
Anyway, problem was solved through rebooting notebook. That's all.