# Touchpad and touchscreen stopped working on dell XPS 13 9360 with ubuntu 16.04.1 They work on liveUSB

Tags: 16.04, touchpad, dell, touchscreen

Tried different guides like [touchpad not working suddenly in Ubuntu 14.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/586420/touchpad-not-working-suddenly-in-ubuntu-14-04)

```
$ xinput
⎡ Virtual core pointer                      id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ Logitech USB Optical Mouse                id=10   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad                id=12   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎣ Virtual core keyboard                     id=3    [master keyboard (2)]
    ↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard               id=5    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=6    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Video Bus                                 id=7    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=8    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Sleep Button                              id=9    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ AT Translated Set 2 keyboard              id=11   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Dell WMI hotkeys                          id=13   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Integrated_Webcam_HD                      id=14   [slave  keyboard (3)]
```

As you can see on xinput comes up only the touchpad but are both shown in the input devices

```
$ cat /proc/bus/input/devices
I: Bus=0019 Vendor=0000 Product=0005 Version=0000
N: Name="Lid Switch"
P: Phys=PNP0C0D/button/input0
S: Sysfs=/devices/LNXSYSTM:00/LNXSYBUS:00/PNP0C0D:00/input/input0
U: Uniq=
H: Handlers=event0 
B: PROP=0
B: EV=21
B: SW=1

I: Bus=0019 Vendor=0000 Product=0001 Version=0000
N: Name="Power Button"
P: Phys=PNP0C0C/button/input0
S: Sysfs=/devices/LNXSYSTM:00/LNXSYBUS:00/PNP0C0C:00/input/input1
U: Uniq=
H: Handlers=kbd event1 
B: PROP=0
B: EV=3
B: KEY=10000000000000 0

I: Bus=0019 Vendor=0000 Product=0003 Version=0000
N: Name="Sleep Button"
P: Phys=PNP0C0E/button/input0
S: Sysfs=/devices/LNXSYSTM:00/LNXSYBUS:00/PNP0C0E:00/input/input2
U: Uniq=
H: Handlers=kbd event2 
B: PROP=0
B: EV=3
B: KEY=4000 0 0

I: Bus=0019 Vendor=0000 Product=0001 Version=0000
N: Name="Power Button"
P: Phys=LNXPWRBN/button/input0
S: Sysfs=/devices/LNXSYSTM:00/LNXPWRBN:00/input/input3
U: Uniq=
H: Handlers=kbd event3 
B: PROP=0
B: EV=3
B: KEY=10000000000000 0

I: Bus=0011 Vendor=0001 Product=0001 Version=ab41
N: Name="AT Translated Set 2 keyboard"
P: Phys=isa0060/serio0/input0
S: Sysfs=/devices/platform/i8042/serio0/input/input4
U: Uniq=
H: Handlers=sysrq kbd event4 leds 
B: PROP=0
B: EV=120013
B: KEY=1100f02902000 8380307cf910f001 feffffdfffefffff fffffffffffffffe
B: MSC=10
B: LED=7

I: Bus=0019 Vendor=0000 Product=0006 Version=0000
N: Name="Video Bus"
P: Phys=LNXVIDEO/video/input0
S: Sysfs=/devices/LNXSYSTM:00/LNXSYBUS:00/PNP0A08:00/LNXVIDEO:00/input/input7
U: Uniq=
H: Handlers=kbd event5 
B: PROP=0
B: EV=3
B: KEY=3e000b00000000 0 0 0

I: Bus=0011 Vendor=0002 Product=0007 Version=01a1
N: Name="SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad"
P: Phys=isa0060/serio1/input0
S: Sysfs=/devices/platform/i8042/serio1/input/input6
U: Uniq=
H: Handlers=mouse0 event6 
B: PROP=5
B: EV=b
B: KEY=e520 10000 0 0 0 0
B: ABS=660800011000003

I: Bus=0003 Vendor=046d Product=c05a Version=0111
N: Name="Logitech USB Optical Mouse"
P: Phys=usb-0000:00:14.0-2/input0
S: Sysfs=/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-2/1-2:1.0/0003:046D:C05A.0001/input/input8
U: Uniq=
H: Handlers=mouse1 event7 
B: PROP=0
B: EV=17
B: KEY=70000 0 0 0 0
B: REL=103
B: MSC=10

I: Bus=0019 Vendor=0000 Product=0000 Version=0000
N: Name="Dell WMI hotkeys"
P: Phys=wmi/input0
S: Sysfs=/devices/virtual/input/input9
U: Uniq=
H: Handlers=kbd event8 
B: PROP=0
B: EV=13
B: KEY=101000b00000400 100000 e000000000000 0
B: MSC=10

I: Bus=0003 Vendor=0bda Product=568b Version=6318
N: Name="Integrated_Webcam_HD"
P: Phys=usb-0000:00:14.0-5/button
S: Sysfs=/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-5/1-5:1.0/input/input10
U: Uniq=
H: Handlers=kbd event9 
B: PROP=0
B: EV=3
B: KEY=100000 0 0 0
```

Booting via liveusb they work fine.

Any clues?

edit: here the same commands that I did run from the live usb:

```
xinput list --long
⎡ Virtual core pointer                      id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
    Reporting 8 classes:
        Class originated from: 12. Type: XIButtonClass
        Buttons supported: 12
        Button labels: "Button Left" "Button Middle" "Button Right" "Button Wheel Up" "Button Wheel Down" "Button Horiz Wheel Left" "Button Horiz Wheel Right" None None None None None
        Button state:
        Class originated from: 12. Type: XIValuatorClass
        Detail for Valuator 0:
          Label: Rel X
          Range: 0.000000 - 1216.000000
          Resolution: 12000 units/m
          Mode: relative
        Class originated from: 12. Type: XIValuatorClass
        Detail for Valuator 1:
          Label: Rel Y
          Range: 0.000000 - 680.000000
          Resolution: 12000 units/m
          Mode: relative
        Class originated from: 12. Type: XIValuatorClass
        Detail for Valuator 2:
          Label: Rel Horiz Scroll
          Range: 0.000000 - -1.000000
          Resolution: 0 units/m
          Mode: relative
        Class originated from: 12. Type: XIValuatorClass
        Detail for Valuator 3:
          Label: Rel Vert Scroll
          Range: 0.000000 - -1.000000
          Resolution: 0 units/m
          Mode: relative
        Class originated from: 12. Type: XIScrollClass
        Scroll info for Valuator 2
          type: 2 (horizontal)
          increment: 27.000000
          flags: 0x0
        Class originated from: 12. Type: XIScrollClass
        Scroll info for Valuator 3
          type: 1 (vertical)
          increment: 27.000000
          flags: 0x0
        Class originated from: 12. Type: XITouchClass
        Touch mode: dependent
        Max number of touches: 5

⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
    Reporting 3 classes:
        Class originated from: 4. Type: XIButtonClass
        Buttons supported: 10
        Button labels: "Button Left" "Button Middle" "Button Right" "Button Wheel Up" "Button Wheel Down" "Button Horiz Wheel Left" "Button Horiz Wheel Right" None None None
        Button state:
        Class originated from: 4. Type: XIValuatorClass
        Detail for Valuator 0:
          Label: Rel X
          Range: -1.000000 - -1.000000
          Resolution: 0 units/m
          Mode: relative
        Class originated from: 4. Type: XIValuatorClass
        Detail for Valuator 1:
          Label: Rel Y
          Range: -1.000000 - -1.000000
          Resolution: 0 units/m
          Mode: relative

⎜   ↳ ELAN Touchscreen                          id=10   [slave  pointer  (2)]
    Reporting 9 classes:
        Class originated from: 10. Type: XIButtonClass
        Buttons supported: 5
        Button labels: "Button Unknown" "Button Unknown" "Button Unknown" "Button Wheel Up" "Button Wheel Down"
        Button state:
        Class originated from: 10. Type: XIValuatorClass
        Detail for Valuator 0:
          Label: Abs MT Position X
          Range: 0.000000 - 3360.000000
          Resolution: 11000 units/m
          Mode: absolute
          Current value: 29.000000
        Class originated from: 10. Type: XIValuatorClass
        Detail for Valuator 1:
          Label: Abs MT Position Y
          Range: 0.000000 - 1872.000000
          Resolution: 11000 units/m
          Mode: absolute
          Current value: 185.000000
        Class originated from: 10. Type: XIValuatorClass
        Detail for Valuator 2:
          Label: Abs MT Touch Major
          Range: 0.000000 - 255.000000
          Resolution: 0 units/m
          Mode: absolute
          Current value: 1.000000
        Class originated from: 10. Type: XIValuatorClass
        Detail for Valuator 3:
          Label: Abs MT Touch Minor
          Range: 0.000000 - 255.000000
          Resolution: 0 units/m
          Mode: absolute
          Current value: 1.000000
        Class originated from: 10. Type: XIValuatorClass
        Detail for Valuator 4:
          Label: Abs MT Orientation
          Range: 0.000000 - 1.000000
          Resolution: 0 units/m
          Mode: absolute
          Current value: 0.000000
        Class originated from: 10. Type: XIValuatorClass
        Detail for Valuator 5:
          Label: Abs MT Tool X
          Range: 0.000000 - 3360.000000
          Resolution: 11000 units/m
          Mode: absolute
          Current value: 29.000000
        Class originated from: 10. Type: XIValuatorClass
        Detail for Valuator 6:
          Label: Abs MT Tool Y
          Range: 0.000000 - 1872.000000
          Resolution: 11000 units/m
          Mode: absolute
          Current value: 186.000000
        Class originated from: 10. Type: XITouchClass
        Touch mode: direct
        Max number of touches: 10

⎜   ↳ DLL075B:01 06CB:76AF Touchpad             id=12   [slave  pointer  (2)]
    Reporting 8 classes:
        Class originated from: 12. Type: XIButtonClass
        Buttons supported: 12
        Button labels: "Button Left" "Button Middle" "Button Right" "Button Wheel Up" "Button Wheel Down" "Button Horiz Wheel Left" "Button Horiz Wheel Right" None None None None None
        Button state:
        Class originated from: 12. Type: XIValuatorClass
        Detail for Valuator 0:
          Label: Rel X
          Range: 0.000000 - 1216.000000
          Resolution: 12000 units/m
          Mode: relative
        Class originated from: 12. Type: XIValuatorClass
        Detail for Valuator 1:
          Label: Rel Y
          Range: 0.000000 - 680.000000
          Resolution: 12000 units/m
          Mode: relative
        Class originated from: 12. Type: XIValuatorClass
        Detail for Valuator 2:
          Label: Rel Horiz Scroll
          Range: 0.000000 - -1.000000
          Resolution: 0 units/m
          Mode: relative
        Class originated from: 12. Type: XIValuatorClass
        Detail for Valuator 3:
          Label: Rel Vert Scroll
          Range: 0.000000 - -1.000000
          Resolution: 0 units/m
          Mode: relative
        Class originated from: 12. Type: XIScrollClass
        Scroll info for Valuator 2
          type: 2 (horizontal)
          increment: 27.000000
          flags: 0x0
        Class originated from: 12. Type: XIScrollClass
        Scroll info for Valuator 3
          type: 1 (vertical)
          increment: 27.000000
          flags: 0x0
        Class originated from: 12. Type: XITouchClass
        Touch mode: dependent
        Max number of touches: 5

⎜   ↳ SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad                id=15   [slave  pointer  (2)]
    Reporting 9 classes:
        Class originated from: 15. Type: XIButtonClass
        Buttons supported: 12
        Button labels: "Button Left" "Button Middle" "Button Right" "Button Wheel Up" "Button Wheel Down" "Button Horiz Wheel Left" "Button Horiz Wheel Right" None None None None None
        Button state:
        Class originated from: 15. Type: XIValuatorClass
        Detail for Valuator 0:
          Label: Rel X
          Range: 1276.000000 - 5666.000000
          Resolution: 0 units/m
          Mode: relative
        Class originated from: 15. Type: XIValuatorClass
        Detail for Valuator 1:
          Label: Rel Y
          Range: 1118.000000 - 4734.000000
          Resolution: 0 units/m
          Mode: relative
        Class originated from: 15. Type: XIValuatorClass
        Detail for Valuator 2:
          Label: Rel Horiz Scroll
          Range: 0.000000 - -1.000000
          Resolution: 0 units/m
          Mode: relative
        Class originated from: 15. Type: XIValuatorClass
        Detail for Valuator 3:
          Label: Rel Vert Scroll
          Range: 0.000000 - -1.000000
          Resolution: 0 units/m
          Mode: relative
        Class originated from: 15. Type: XIValuatorClass
        Detail for Valuator 4:
          Label: Abs MT Pressure
          Range: 0.000000 - 255.000000
          Resolution: 0 units/m
          Mode: absolute
          Current value: 0.000000
        Class originated from: 15. Type: XIScrollClass
        Scroll info for Valuator 2
          type: 2 (horizontal)
          increment: 113.000000
          flags: 0x0
        Class originated from: 15. Type: XIScrollClass
        Scroll info for Valuator 3
          type: 1 (vertical)
          increment: 113.000000
          flags: 0x0
        Class originated from: 15. Type: XITouchClass
        Touch mode: dependent
        Max number of touches: 2

⎣ Virtual core keyboard                     id=3    [master keyboard (2)]
    Reporting 1 classes:
        Class originated from: 14. Type: XIKeyClass
        Keycodes supported: 248

    ↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard               id=5    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    Reporting 1 classes:
        Class originated from: 5. Type: XIKeyClass
        Keycodes supported: 248

    ↳ Power Button                              id=6    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    Reporting 1 classes:
        Class originated from: 6. Type: XIKeyClass
        Keycodes supported: 248

    ↳ Video Bus                                 id=7    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    Reporting 1 classes:
        Class originated from: 7. Type: XIKeyClass
        Keycodes supported: 248

    ↳ Power Button                              id=8    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    Reporting 1 classes:
        Class originated from: 8. Type: XIKeyClass
        Keycodes supported: 248

    ↳ Sleep Button                              id=9    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    Reporting 1 classes:
        Class originated from: 9. Type: XIKeyClass
        Keycodes supported: 248

    ↳ Integrated_Webcam_HD                      id=11   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    Reporting 1 classes:
        Class originated from: 11. Type: XIKeyClass
        Keycodes supported: 248

    ↳ Intel HID events                          id=13   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    Reporting 1 classes:
        Class originated from: 13. Type: XIKeyClass
        Keycodes supported: 248

    ↳ AT Translated Set 2 keyboard              id=14   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    Reporting 1 classes:
        Class originated from: 14. Type: XIKeyClass
        Keycodes supported: 248

    ↳ Dell WMI hotkeys                          id=16   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    Reporting 1 classes:
        Class originated from: 16. Type: XIKeyClass
        Keycodes supported: 248

$ cat /proc/
I: Bus=0019 Vendor=0000 Product=0005 Version=0000
N: Name="Lid Switch"
P: Phys=PNP0C0D/button/input0
S: Sysfs=/devices/LNXSYSTM:00/LNXSYBUS:00/PNP0C0D:00/input/input0
U: Uniq=
H: Handlers=event0 
B: PROP=0
B: EV=21
B: SW=1

I: Bus=0019 Vendor=0000 Product=0001 Version=0000
N: Name="Power Button"
P: Phys=PNP0C0C/button/input0
S: Sysfs=/devices/LNXSYSTM:00/LNXSYBUS:00/PNP0C0C:00/input/input1
U: Uniq=
H: Handlers=kbd event1 
B: PROP=0
B: EV=3
B: KEY=10000000000000 0

I: Bus=0019 Vendor=0000 Product=0003 Version=0000
N: Name="Sleep Button"
P: Phys=PNP0C0E/button/input0
S: Sysfs=/devices/LNXSYSTM:00/LNXSYBUS:00/PNP0C0E:00/input/input2
U: Uniq=
H: Handlers=kbd event2 
B: PROP=0
B: EV=3
B: KEY=4000 0 0

I: Bus=0019 Vendor=0000 Product=0001 Version=0000
N: Name="Power Button"
P: Phys=LNXPWRBN/button/input0
S: Sysfs=/devices/LNXSYSTM:00/LNXPWRBN:00/input/input3
U: Uniq=
H: Handlers=kbd event3 
B: PROP=0
B: EV=3
B: KEY=10000000000000 0

I: Bus=0011 Vendor=0001 Product=0001 Version=ab41
N: Name="AT Translated Set 2 keyboard"
P: Phys=isa0060/serio0/input0
S: Sysfs=/devices/platform/i8042/serio0/input/input4
U: Uniq=
H: Handlers=sysrq kbd event4 leds 
B: PROP=0
B: EV=120013
B: KEY=1100f02902000 8380307cf910f001 feffffdfffefffff fffffffffffffffe
B: MSC=10
B: LED=7

I: Bus=0019 Vendor=0000 Product=0006 Version=0000
N: Name="Video Bus"
P: Phys=LNXVIDEO/video/input0
S: Sysfs=/devices/LNXSYSTM:00/LNXSYBUS:00/PNP0A08:00/LNXVIDEO:00/input/input7
U: Uniq=
H: Handlers=kbd event5 
B: PROP=0
B: EV=3
B: KEY=3e000b00000000 0 0 0

I: Bus=0011 Vendor=0002 Product=0007 Version=01a1
N: Name="SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad"
P: Phys=isa0060/serio1/input0
S: Sysfs=/devices/platform/i8042/serio1/input/input6
U: Uniq=
H: Handlers=mouse0 event6 
B: PROP=5
B: EV=b
B: KEY=e520 10000 0 0 0 0
B: ABS=660800011000003

I: Bus=0019 Vendor=0000 Product=0000 Version=0000
N: Name="Intel HID events"
P: Phys=
S: Sysfs=/devices/platform/INT33D5:00/input/input8
U: Uniq=
H: Handlers=rfkill kbd event7 
B: PROP=0
B: EV=13
B: KEY=81000300000000 5000004000 1e294000000020 0
B: MSC=10

I: Bus=0003 Vendor=04f3 Product=20d0 Version=0110
N: Name="ELAN Touchscreen"
P: Phys=usb-0000:00:14.0-4/input0
S: Sysfs=/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-4/1-4:1.0/0003:04F3:20D0.0001/input/input9
U: Uniq=
H: Handlers=mouse1 event8 
B: PROP=2
B: EV=b
B: KEY=400 0 0 0 0 0
B: ABS=3273800000000003

I: Bus=0003 Vendor=0bda Product=568b Version=6318
N: Name="Integrated_Webcam_HD"
P: Phys=usb-0000:00:14.0-5/button
S: Sysfs=/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-5/1-5:1.0/input/input11
U: Uniq=
H: Handlers=kbd event9 
B: PROP=0
B: EV=3
B: KEY=100000 0 0 0

I: Bus=0019 Vendor=0000 Product=0000 Version=0000
N: Name="Dell WMI hotkeys"
P: Phys=wmi/input0
S: Sysfs=/devices/virtual/input/input12
U: Uniq=
H: Handlers=kbd event10 
B: PROP=0
B: EV=13
B: KEY=101000b00000400 100000 e000000000000 0
B: MSC=10

I: Bus=0018 Vendor=06cb Product=76af Version=0100
N: Name="DLL075B:01 06CB:76AF Touchpad"
P: Phys=i2c-DLL075B:01
S: Sysfs=/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:15.1/i2c_designware.1/i2c-7/i2c-DLL075B:01/0018:06CB:76AF.0002/input/input13
U: Uniq=
H: Handlers=mouse2 event11 
B: PROP=5
B: EV=b
B: KEY=e520 10000 0 0 0 0
B: ABS=260800000000003
```

at this link [the complete xorg log on the live cd](https://www.dropbox.com/s/fp68dhp6ty1g6d7/Xorg.0.log?dl=0)
here instead [the complete xorg log on the "normal" install](https://www.dropbox.com/s/231w5nizkgr3arb/Xorg.0.log-normal?dl=0)

Comment: tried kernel 4.4.0-21-generic, touchpad and touchscreen work but not network devices & HiDPI scaling

Comment: with kernel 4.4.0-23-generic network devices & HiDPI working but not touchscreen and touchpad

Comment: difference between [lsmod outputs with kernel 21 & 57] (https://www.diffchecker.com/eoMdbbPC)

Comment: differences between lsmod outputs with kernel 21 and 57 https://www.diffchecker.com/eoMdbbPC

Comment: as suggested on irc channel #ubuntu, tried this solution, to no avail http://pastebin.com/g7Pi1sBp

Comment: ok, tried also with 16.04.1 live, kernel 4.4.0-31-generic same as 4.4.0-21-generic

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Followed [this](http://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2016/12/install-linux-kernel-4-9-ubuntu-linux-mint/) guide to install kernel 4.9 now everything works